# .Net Core MVC | How to redirect back to the calling page

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a problem with my CRUD application, I have two CRUDs one for Products and other for Categories.
When I am editing Product I have a dropdown list with categories and an action link ( + Add Category) to redirect to the Categories controller action to add a new category. My problem is that once I click to add new category I'm redirected to another controller Categories/Create and after submitting the new category it goes to Categories/Index.
I would like it to go back to the edited product eg. Products/Edit/5. I am not sure how to approach. I have used the JS script onClick to go back in history -1 but it's not the right solution for it.

This is my ActionResult for the Categories Controller.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] Category category)
    {
        var categoryList = _context.Categories.ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var item in categoryList)
            {
                if (category.Name.Trim() == item.Name)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Already Exists!");
                    return View();
                }
            }
            _context.Add(category);
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

My View

```html
This is my View
<form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In **.Net Core 3.1** just put this line inside your controller method will redirect to the previous page

`return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"]);`

That is all you need.... Check it out